# private files with django-queued-storages + boto + amazon s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

So i have `django-queued-storages` + `django-storages` + `boto` in my project and i want to upload my pdf files to S3 and immediately make them private.

i have tried many approaches with no results them being:

```
publication_storage = QueuedStorage(
    local='django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage',
    remote='storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage',
    remote_options=dict(acl="private")
)
```

and it didn't put my file as private.

i also tried something like this based on http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2012/09/26/django-s3-temporary.php:

```
      k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
      k.key = settings.MEDIA_DIRECTORY + self.private_file
      k.set_acl('private')
```

all of these still kept my uploaded PDF acessible to the outside.

Can anyone help me out? maybe a full example so i can try it, i have tried lots of things that i found on google with no luck yet

Comment: I use the exact same code in my project and it works flawlessly. It appends a `?signature=xxx` to the file URL. The signature is a really long string. If someone knows the signature, they can access the file. Does that look like something you're getting?

Comment: @AshishKasturia which code of the above?? anyways i do get a signature after i upload the file and click on the link. but if i remove the signature i shouldn't be able to access the file but i still am. isn't that right?

Comment: The second one with `k.set_acl('private')`. You're right about not being able to access the file without the signature. Also, make sure the folder inside the S3 bucket is set to private under 'Permissions'

Comment: but i am serving my static files from the same bucket and inside i have `static` and `media` . if i set it to private wont that affect my static file?? would you be kind enough to share some code of your where you got that working?

Comment: I currently don't have access to my laptop, I will post my code snippet in the evening if that's okay with you. Also, I just checked my S3 bucket, and you're right. You cannot assign permissions to individual folders, only on the bucket. My bucket is public, but individual files are private because of `k.set_acl('private')`. Can you click on the checkbox next to an uploaded file, and check it's properties?

Comment: it says this on the console:
`>>> print key.key`
`media/private/publications/75d9114e4af84f19a13a7ae50ec262/75d9114e4af84f1_2_cover_original.png`
`>>> acp = key.get_acl()`
`>>> print acp`
`<Policy: pfblacerda (owner) = FULL_CONTROL>`
`>>> key.set_acl('private')`
'>>> acp = key.get_acl()`
`>>> print acp`
`<Policy: pfblacerda (owner) = FULL_CONTROL>`

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you (owner) have full control? Try this... open an incognito browser tab or window, and then try to access the file without the signature.

Comment: i tried it and it still allows access :( tried clearing the cache as well and also tried another browser

Comment: What does it say under the 'Properties/Permissions' section for the file on the S3 panel?

Comment: it only says grantee `pfblacerda` that has all the permissions, no one else

Comment: Then it is setting the right permissions. Try opening a brand new incognito browser tab, don't log in to S3, access the file URL without the signature bit.

Comment: still nothing. i was just thinking. do i need some special bucket permissions even though i also want to make my static files open? this is what i have now https://gist.github.com/psychok7/493ecb6d047f98103475

Comment: Damn. I'm out of ideas now. One last thing. Try making the bucket private, then right click on the static folder and click on 'Make public'.

Comment: @AshishKasturia i think its working now. you last solution worked. made bucket private and then only made de static foder public. i hope i dont run into problems with the static folder because of that

Comment: you can put it as an answer and ill mark it has correct :)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it worked out for you. Adding an answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back and forth with you, this is what worked.

Since you have both `media` and `static` under the same bucket, make the bucket private. Then only make the `static` folder public by right clicking on the folder in the S3 admin panel and clicking on 'Make public'.

As for the `media` folder, your second block of code should suffice

```
  k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
  k.key = settings.MEDIA_DIRECTORY + self.private_file
  k.set_acl('private')
```

This was also educational for me as I have two separate buckets on S3, one for uploads and one for static. So naturally I didn't run into this problem.

Good luck to you.

Comment: If the `media` folder is private in the S3 admin panel as you mentioned, do I need to make the files inside it explicitly private as well, using code (e.g. `k.set_acl('private')`? I'm confused.